# Пауза в игре на Sprite Kit ios 7

Tags: spritekit, objective-c, ios, ios7

Доброго времени суток. Постораюсь кратко.
Есть SkScene с игрой и нужно реализовать паузу с переходом на другую сцену или же отрисовкой меню на этой.
Для остановки происходящего на сцене использую `self.scene.paused = YES;`

Для перехода к другой сцене `[self.view presentScene:sceneWithMenu];`

Вот только не могу вернуться обратно на сцену с игрой и продолжить её. Нагуглить ничего полезного не смог. Помогите пожалуйста. Как мне решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте более детально изучить документацию, связанную с переходами между игровыми сценами. Советую обратить Ваше внимание на свойство: `pausesIncomingScene`. 
Увы, подробней объяснить и привести пример кода в данную минуту не представляется возможным.

[Соответствующая документация](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKTransition/pausesIncomingScene)